# How to rewrite no_data_found exception into a user-defined exception?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here's the code which catches the Oracle exception

```
set serveroutput on;
ACCEPT identifiant PROMPT 'id';
DECLARE
    vType PARCELLE.TypeP%Type;
    vSuperf PARCELLE.Superf%Type;
BEGIN
    SELECT distinct TypeP,Superf INTO vType,vSuperf
    FROM PARCELLE
    WHERE PARCELLE.NumPropC='&identifiant' 
    AND Superf=(select MAX(Superf) from PARCELLE
      where PARCELLE.NumPropC='&identifiant');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('id:'||'&identifiant'||',type:'||vType
      ||',Supeficie:'||vSuperf);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Aucun Propriétaire vous cherchez.');  
END;
```

What I need to do now is write another version which does not use the built-in exception but uses a user-defined exception. The result should be the same.

I tried something like this

```
BEGIN
    SELECT distinct TypeP,Superf INTO vType,vSuperf
    FROM PARCELLE
    WHERE PARCELLE.NumPropC='&identifiant' 
    AND Superf=(select MAX(Superf) from PARCELLE 
      where PARCELLE.NumPropC='&identifiant');
    IF vType IS NULL OR vSuperf IS NULL THEN RAISE non_trouve;
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('id:'||'&identifiant'||',type:'||vType
      ||',Supeficie:'||vSuperf);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN non_trouve THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Aucun Propriétaire vous cherchez.');
```

Before it gets to the condition to jump to the exception, it returns the built-in exception (not found) first.

And I tried another way like:

```
DECLARE
    vType PARCELLE.TypeP%Type;
    vSuperf PARCELLE.Superf%Type;
    non_trouve EXCEPTION;
    vToutProp PROPRIETAIRE.NumPropC%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO vToutProp FROM PROPRIETAIRE;
    IF '&identifiant' NOT IN (vToutProp) THEN RAISE non_trouve;
    END IF;
--same left
```

But it is totally wrong because I should declare an array or something but I have no idea how to deal with it.

Any one has an idea?

Comment: _"what I need to do now, is to write another version which does not use ORACLE exception but user-defined exception."_   **Why?** Seriously .. not sure why you'd want to make this harder than it has to be? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If this is an exercise you've been given then it's hard to guess what your tutor is looking for, as it will depend on what you've been taught so far (or recently). Fairly obvious ways to tackle it (if you must - as Ditto says you're making life overly complicated) are to have a sub-block that catches the built-in exception and raises yours instead, or querying for max/min of the columns and seeing if they are (both) null, which only works if they're not-null columns. Incidentally, replacing an exception with `dbms_output` is another bad idea.

Comment: You can define custom exception names using [`PRAGMA EXCEPTION INIT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#LNPLS00704), but note that `no_data_found` has a disclaimer: "*Because this exception is used internally by some SQL functions to signal completion, you must not rely on this exception being propagated if you raise it within a function that is invoked as part of a query.*"

Comment: Yes, it's a school exercise and ... the question is like "write exceptions while the owner(proprietaire) is not exist in (i)user-defined exception (ii) ORACLE exception", it should just be an simple application of what we learned, never thought it would be so complicated. I'll do some more tries. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not allowed to use in-built exception, use the count function to check if the data exists. If not, raise a custom exception.

```
set serveroutput ON;
ACCEPT identifiant prompt 'id';
DECLARE
    v_count NUMBER := 0;
    e_non_trouve EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    SELECT Count(1)
    INTO   v_count
    FROM   parcelle
    WHERE  parcelle.numpropc = '&identifiant'
           AND superf = (SELECT Max(superf)
                         FROM   parcelle
                         WHERE  parcelle.numpropc = '&identifiant');


    IF v_count = 0 THEN
      RAISE e_non_trouve;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN e_non_trouve THEN
      dbms_output.Put_line('Aucun Propriétaire vous cherchez.');
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm stuck in trying to find a way to deal with the "null" result but dropped into a dead loop. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will  help.  In Oracle PL SQL you can create your own exceptions like below

```
  PROCEDURE ProcedureName

  IS
     CUSTOM_EXCEPTION  EXCEPTION;

  BEGIN

     -- code here
     RAISE CUSTOM_EXCEPTION

  EXCEPTION
     WHEN CUSTOM_EXCEPTION THEN
        -- code for CUSTOM_EXCEPTION

  END ProcedureName
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be honest, you do not "need to do now" anything of this kind if all you're going to do is absorb the exception like you do in the sample code. Off the top of my head, I can only think of two reasons to use user-defined exceptions:

1. You want to propagate an exception outside the procedure and you want it to be something meaningful to the caller. So you want to turn "no data found" into "that student is not currently enrolled in that class."
2. There are several locations within the procedure that could raise a "no data found" exception, but the significance (and thus the meaning) is different depending on where it is raised. You want the outer level exception handler to be able to discern the difference.

If the second option, it might be as good or better to do something like this:

```
err_code := 1;
-- perform something that might raise no_data_found
...
err_code := 2;
-- perform something else that might raise no_data_found
...
err_code := 3;
-- perform something else that might raise no_data_found
...
exception
    when no_data_found then
        if err_code = 1 then
            Raise_application_error( -20001, 'Student not enrolled in that class';
        elsif err_code = 2 then
            Raise_application_error( -20001, 'Student not making a passing grade in class';
        elsif err_code = 3 then
            Raise_application_error( -20001, 'Only you can prevent forest fires!';
        end if;
    when others then
        -- uh-oh
end proc;
```

It's not fancy, but it gets the job done.